Как заменить стандартную иконку accordion из vuetify на свою?

пытался заменить css свойствами, не помогло:
::v-deep.mdi-chevron-down::before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 64" fill="none"><circle cx="31.8136" cy="31.8151" r="22" transform="rotate(-46.1348 31.8136 31.8151)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#AD7B66"/><path d="M24.5469 24.8281L39.0906 38.8069" stroke="#AD7B66" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/><path d="M24.8281 39.0898L38.8069 24.5461" stroke="#AD7B66" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/></svg>');
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

